# Print the 2-dimensional list mult_table by row and column

Tags: python

what am I doing wrong here? I can't seem to figure this out

```
mult_table = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [3, 6, 9]
]
```

i tried typing this code in and it gave me this kind of error how do I get ride of the last line from 3, 6, 9

```
for row in mult_table:
         for cell in row:
            print(cell,'|',end ='')
        print()

    error   1 |2 |3 |
            2 |4 |6 |
            3 |6 |9 |
```

Comment: please put the code into the question so it's easier to copy/paste/edit

Comment: You need to include the code *in* the question, or it's likely to get removed. Also tell us what you've tried to get the expected answer. Anyway, I encourage you to look at str.join()

Comment: since 3,6,9 appears twice in your matrix, your question is somewhat unclear. I believe you are asking how you remove the rightmost vertical line from the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can join strings of the elements with pipes:

```
for row in multi_table:
    print (' | '.join([str(r) for r in row]))
```

If the pipe's are not surrounded by spaces:

```
for row in multi_table:
    print ('|'.join([str(r) for r in row]))
```

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to remove the last column, but the code below will do it.

```
mult_table = [[1, 2, 3],[2, 4, 6],[3, 6, 9]]

for row in mult_table:
    rowLen=len(row)
    for i in range(0,rowLen-1):
        print(row[i], '|', end = '')
    print()
```

Output

```
1 |2 |
2 |4 | 
3 |6 |
```

Comment: He doesn't want to get rid of the last column, he wants to get rid of the `|` *after* the last column.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did some digging around and going with what I know. Here is the solution to this challenge. You do not need to add a variable to mult_table. I thought you did but resolved that with this code:

```
for row in mult_table:
     for cell in row:
         if cell == row[len(row) -1]:
            print(cell, end='')
         else:
             print(cell, end=' | ')
     print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

```
for row in mult_table:
    for cell in row:
        if cell == row[len(row) -1]:
            print(cell, end='')
            print()      
        else: 
            print(cell,'| ',end ='')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the modern zybooks lab this is how I was able to run the code without any errors and without copying code from here word for word

```
user_input = input()
lines = user_input.split(',')

# This line uses a construct called a list comprehension, introduced elsewhere,
# to convert the input string into a two-dimensional list.
# Ex: 1 2, 2 4 is converted to [ [1, 2], [2, 4] ]

mult_table = [[int(num) for num in line.split()] for line in lines]

# This part below is what I wrote the part above was the default code template
for row in mult_table:
    for x in row:
        if x != row[-1]:
            print(x, end=" | ")
        else:
            print(x)
```